# how to navigate a map in clojure in a similar way to threading

Tags: clojure

Is there a nicer way to navigate though a nested map in clojure.  E.g. for the following map:

```
{
  :one{
    :two {
      :three value
     }
   }
}
```

To get the value of `:three` I do `(:three (:two (:one mymap)))` but it would be much nicer if there was something like threading where I could do `(-> mymap :one :two :three)`

Comment: By the way, your threading example should just work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"it would be much nicer if there was something like threading where I could do `(-> mymap :one :two :three)`"**

Who says you can't? Your exact syntax works!

```
so.core=> (def mymap { :one, { :two, { :three :value } } })
#'so.core/mymap
so.core=> (-> mymap :one :two :three)
:value
```

Comment: Not only that, but `(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(-> mymap :one :two :three))` gives exactly the original `(:three (:two (:one mymap)))` syntax!

Comment: Apologies for not actually trying it before I asked the question! At least other people might find this page helpful as I couldn't find anything with google and that's why I asked.

Answer (score 6):

The core function get-in fits exactly your requirement

```
Returns the value in a nested associative structure,
where ks is a sequence of ke(ys. Returns nil if the key is not present,
or the not-found value if supplied.


(get-in your-nested-data [:one :two :three])
```

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get-in